# jquery colorbox: first image not loading

Tags: colorbox

I'm having an odd problem with colorbox. The first image refuses to load on the first cycle of the slideshow. On subsequent cycles it loads fine.

page link: http://www.moongraf.com/ddf/weddings.html

click on the photo gallery link in the text

Image size for testing is under 8k so its not an image size issue. Slideshow speed is 4000, relatively slow.

I have another page upladed that works fine using the same links to css/js files in the head content: http://www.moongraf.com/ddf/eventsOLD.html

I must be missing something but I can't find anything that looks wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I found the answer. Dreamweaver was rewriting my code and deleting the link to jquery.min.js. Nice.